# nested forms django, nested models

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have two classes say A and b in django models

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True)

class Facility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

I want to create django admin form so that I can edit both Facility name and address when I add Facility object in admin interface.

I dont want the reverse, means I dont want to edit Facility name when I add Address object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about inline admin?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin